# Returning a 2-dimensional array of doubles from function

Tags: c++

I have this class in which at some point I am computing a array of two doubles:

```
double* QSweep::computeIntersection(double m1, double b1, double m2, double b2){
double* v=new double[2];

v[0]= (b2-b1)/(m1-m2);
v[1]= (m1*b2-m2*b1)/(m1-m2);

return v;
}
```

In another function of the class I am using this array to work with its values.
Depending on the values transmitted as parameters I obtained several values for this array of two daoubles. And I want to retain all this values in a array of array of two doubles.
I have tried some ways but I have bur error, segementation fault or all problems as this.
Any idea is welcomed.

thank you in advance,
madalina

Comment: Actually, that's not a two dimensional array, it's an array with dimension 2.

Comment: no, really the question is providing detail about 2 one dimensional arrays one containing the other, array ( array (double) ). this could be turned into a 2d array or many other structs.

Answer (score 9):

If they are always two values, wouldn't it be more logical (and more useful) to return a `std::pair<double, double>`? This might save a lot of pain, especially related to explicit memory management (since you're using `new`/`delete`):

```
std::pair<double, double> QSweep::computeIntersection(
    double m1, double b1, double m2, double b2
) {
    return std::make_pair( (b2-b1)/(m1-m2), (m1*b2-m2*b1)/(m1-m2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is to change the signature:

```
void QSweep::computeIntersection(double m1, double b1, double m2, double b2, double& return_v0, double& return_v1)
{
    return_v0 = (b2-b1)/(m1-m2);
    return_v1 = (m1*b2-m2*b1)/(m1-m2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have a type called Intersection, which is done very quickly:

```
typedef std::pair<double, double> Intersection
```

Or perhaps there should be something more explicit in there, because the members of pair are "first" and "second" and perhaps you might want something more descriptive.

In any case, you'd rather return these things by value than returning a pointer to heap-allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't include enough to be able to provide an answer to your question about why it's crashing.

The following example would ensure that there are no memory leaks from un-freed pointers, and keeps a similar structure.

```
typedef std::pair<double, double> Intersection;
typedef std::vector<Intersection> Plane;

Intersection QSweep::computeIntersection
  ( double m1
  , double b1
  , double m2
  , double b2) 
{
    return Intersection( (b2-b1)/(m1-m2), (m1*b2-m2*b1)/(m1-m2));
}

main() 
{
  Plane plane;
  while( input ){
    plane.push_back( Intersection( ... ) );
  }
}
```

There could be other ways of storing this, for instance as you are using double, you could use calloc and realloc to maintain one piece of memory the right size. (don't recommend it given your example so far)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector` to maintain your history of doubles.  If you continue to use an array of doubles, to hold onto them, do something like this:

```
std::vector<double*> history;
history.push_back(v);
```

Note, you will still need to `delete` the memory pointed to by each element when you are done with the vector (or individual vector elements).  In order to get around this, use a `pair` to track your original array of doubles (if you are just using two), or a `vector<double>`.

Comment: Why am I down voted?  Read the question, the original poster wants to know how to store off the 1-d array in a 2-d array later on.

Answer (score 0):

Given that what you have is an array of two doubles, i wouldn't doubt there is a need to raise that number up at some time. Like, if at some point you decide to add 3d functions too. I would therefor prefer to stay with an array. But there is no need to use a dynamic array. Use an array wrapped in a struct like `boost::array`:

```
boost::array<double, 2> QSweep::computeIntersection(
    double m1, double b1, double m2, double b2
) {
    boost::array<double, 2> array = { (b2-b1)/(m1-m2),  (m1*b2-m2*b1)/(m1-m2) };
    return array;
}
```

Then you can add it to a vector which will contain those:

```
typedef std::vector< boost::array<double, 2> > vec_of_2darray_t;
vec_of_2darray_t v;
v.push_back(computeIntersection(a, b, c, d));
// ...
```

This is probably the best you can get if you aim for both simplicity and extensibility.[`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/array.html) is a pretty small and simple struct. It basically amounts to

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct array { T data[N]; };
```

And several functions, of course, like `operator[]`, `begin()` and `end()` and other stuff. But without constructors, so that you can initialize it like a normal array as we did above.

Answer (score 0):

thank you:),
it worked with push_back the value obtained each time in a new vector of type

```
vector <double *>,
```

madalina